# comparing two columns

Tags: text-processing

I want to print OK if in column3 all fields are OK from below output.

```
port    mcg clk  stat
 ------  -------  ----
 OK      EXTCLK1  OK  
 OK      CLK3B    OK  
 OK      CLK3A    OK
```

I have tried like this

```
a=`cat file2.txt | awk '{if ($1 == $3) {print "sync is OK";} else { print "sync is NOK";}}'`
echo "$a" > file3.txt
```

here it if conditions is satisfied thrice so it is printing ok three times but I want to print only once.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
awk 'BEGIN { ok=1 ; } 
      NR>2 { $3 != "OK" ; print "sync is NOK"; ok = 0 ; exit ; } 
      END { if ( ok ) print "sync is OK";} ' file2.txt > file3.txt
```

this will print a single NOK/OK. (note that script can be one-lined).